# Mechanism of Screenshot

Tags: screen-capture

Basically I with my team are figuring out a way to block screenshots taken on our corporation's computers (Mac mostly). I have searched it extensively and found that there is something called Screen buffer which is being accessed by any screenshot taking software (eg. Snipping Tool etc). I tried to find the exact mechanism and the actual implementation of such softwares but with no luck. Also I found out that Netflix uses some kind of technology which corrupts screenshot image and blackens it. I did not find any actual mechanism or implementation to study it further. I also came across something called Hardware overlays but did not understand it properly in order to use it for actual implementation. I have considered a way to edit scancode maps in registry but I am looking for a more general way. I read a few articles for apple's FPS though. Can somebody please guide me through this? Some good resources for the same would be highly appreciated. Any particular or relevant forums or subs to discuss this are also welcome

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've been barking up the wrong tree for a little while. A screen buffer is a generic programming concept which does not describe the situation in macos well. Hardware overlay will likely only affect what appears on the monitor, not what appears in a screenshot. And Netflix's method is no more interesting that DVD Player's method.

Fortunately, this question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4239685/3697870) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48521698/3697870) on the sister Stack Overflow site. Basically there is a private API that allows this, but being private you're best to talk directly to Apple about it via a DTS request.

Comment: Okay. I will try to read and understand what exactly screen capture softwares do like what api calls and relevent requests and then will try to focus on how to prevent it. Could you cite some resources to study them?

Comment: As Heath has mentioned this is a private API from Apple so you need to contact them...