# Screen Capture on MacOS

Tags: macos, screen-capture

Its been a while I am looking for mechanism of screen capture in MacOS. Even with extensive googling I found no luck with its actual mechanism. Can somebody guide me through some good resources or even better the actual mechanism and implementation of screen capture (with api calls and functioning)?
Thanks

Comment: This is basically the same question that you asked 2 days ago - the answer was contact Apple as it is their private API ...

Comment: Earlier I was asking for a method to prevent screen captures. In this question however the situation is vice versa. I need a method/implementation to write a screen capture program. I believe this is different from my previous question

Answer (score 2):

You can record the screen with QuickTime Player, included in the OS:

File -> New Screen Recording

If you want programmatic access, you can find the API here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturescreeninput

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me through this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313970/mechanism-of-screenshot/
Highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe [Heath Raftery's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239685/can-i-prevent-a-user-from-taking-screenshots-in-a-mac-application/48521698#48521698) is the best answer for your question. It seems the only **reliable** way to get this done is asking [Apple's Developer Technical Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) for access to the private API needed. However, it may be that they do not intend anyone to have the ability, because even extremely popular applications (ie. Snapchat) are unable to prevent it.